# Email button on opportunity detail page to send opportunity field info

Tags: custom-button

I want to create a custom email button on the opportunity detail page which would capture data from few fields and send those data via email to a recipient.

Could anyone please suggest me a way to achieve this? If you have a code that you can share that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried something yourself?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the questions about "URL hacking" or "emailAuthor.jsp" for a good start. You can create url that would be populating the fields on the email sending page (even preselect an email template which most of the time is better option than crafting it by hand) and even auto-simulate sending it if you don't want the user to preview it before sending.

Comment: No, I din't try anything myself. Was wondering do I have to use Apex code for this or can we achieve this through some customization?

Answer (score 1):

You can call an apex method to trigger mail from custom js button on detail page.{Classic only}

```
global class MyClass
{
    webservice static void sendEmail(oppid, amnt, somethingelse) // you can pass parameters
    { 
         // your send email code.
    }
}
```

on detail page button select behavior as 'Execute JavaScript'
content source as 'Onclick JavaScript', and use below code to call a method.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
if("{!Opportunity.Id}" != null){
sforce.apex.execute("myClass","sendEmail",{oppid:"{!Opportunity.Id}",amnt:"{!Opportunity.Amount}", somethingelse: "something else"});
}
```